# How do i scan all of the directories' files for hashes and compare it with my list of hashes?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

I am making a application that scans file's hashes and if that hash matches a hash on my text file it flags it as a "MATCH" this is my code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Quick_Scan
{
    class Program
    {
        public static String GetHash<T>(Stream stream) where T : HashAlgorithm
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            MethodInfo create = typeof(T).GetMethod("Create", new Type[] { });
            using (T crypt = (T)create.Invoke(null, null))
            {
                byte[] hashBytes = crypt.ComputeHash(stream);
                foreach (byte bt in hashBytes)
                {
                    sb.Append(bt.ToString("x2"));
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int precentagedone = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Quick Scan v1.0");
            Console.WriteLine("Starting scan...");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned "+precentagedone+"%");
            using (FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead("hashes.txt"))
            {
                GetHash<MD5>(fStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im not using some of these USING library thingies because i just follow some random question answers that dont work then nothing work
how do i "scan" all the files of a directory i have a file called hashes.txt one line on that file is a hash and i want to compare those to any of the files on a directory how do i do that?

Comment: for some reason it ends it instantly i only want the program to end when it has scanned 100% of a directory how do i do that too?

Comment: It looks like you are new to programming ("using library thingies") and you're trying to get code you found on the internet to work ("random question answers"), but this isn't a service where you can get people to write code for you. You have to try to solve the problem yourself. But, I'll give you a piece of advice. If you want to compare the hashes, you are going to need to do compute the file hashes first. In the above code all you are doing is opening the hashes.txt file, you are not iterating through any actual files and computing the hashes for them.